# Is there a way to have pattern lock that doesn't prompt for X minutes yet still requires some action other than pushing a button (e.g. like iOS)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, pattern-lock

I want the lock screen for my Android (currently running a CyanogenMod 10.2 nightly) to behave more like that of iOS, where I can have a delay on when I need to re-enter the pattern/pass-code, but still require a swipe every time screen is turned off.  The existing "Automatic Lock [after X time]" feature lacks this additional swipe I describe.

My goal is to have the phone locked down after X minutes (e.g. 15), yet not be susceptible to easy unlocking during this time (e.g. power or home button getting pressed accidentally while in my pocket).

I would prefer to not use a 3rd party app, but I suppose that can't be avoided unless there's an existing setting that I'm not seeing.  If there is a reputable 3rd party lock screen app with this functionality, I'll take that as well.